# Is it possible to quicksort objects based on their keys in an array, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, quicksort

To clarify a bit on the question, I have an array and within the array are a bunch of objects. Can I rearrange the objects in the array based on the key values of each object?

When I'm attempting to do so, it keeps telling me that the variable (in this case, students) is undefined.

When I use the built-in sort function, it works perfectly. However, this is a school assignment and I HAVE to show the breakdown of the quicksort function.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        function swap(student, firstIndex, secondIndex){
            var temp = student[firstIndex];
            student[firstIndex] = student[secondIndex];
            student[secondIndex] = temp;
        }

        function partition(student, left, right) {

            var pivot   = student[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
                i       = left,
                j       = right;


            while (i <= j) {

                while (student[i] < pivot) {
                    i++;
                }

                while (student[j] > pivot) {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j) {
                    swap(student, i, j);
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            return i;
        }

        function quickSort(student, left, right) {

            var index;

            if (student.length > 1) {

                left = typeof left != "number" ? 0 : left;
                right = typeof right != "number" ? student.length - 1 : right;

                index = partition(student, left, right);
                if (left < index - 1) {
                    quickSort(student, left, index - 1);
                }

                if (index < right) {
                    quickSort(student, index, right);
                }

            }

            return student;
        }

    var studentNumbersArray = []

    var randomArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) { 
        studentNumbersArray.push(studentsArray[i].studentNumber);              
    }


    function sortStudentNumbers() {    
        var student = studentNumbersArray.name; // <-- THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING ERROR
        quickSort(student);
        var updatedStudentArray = JSON.stringify(studentsArray);
        localStorage.setItem("students", updatedStudentArray); 
        location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: You don't have *students variable* assigned to any value any where.

Comment: why the `.name` in the line that creates the error?

Comment: @ilter i declare it under the sortStudentNumbers function, `var student = studentNumbersArray.name;`

Comment: @ammoQ it says that student (studentNumbersArray.name) is undefined

Comment: There is no field `name` in `studentNumbersArray`, what do you expect?

Comment: @ammoQ I'm sorry I copied the wrong parts of my code :$ :$ I'll delete this topic and open up a new one with proper code when I get a chance to get on laptop

Comment: Can you edit this question into shape please? You seem to have an introductory paragraph, then a code sample (that's great) and then you've pasted it all in again. If the code samples are different, please delete the one you don't want, and ditto with the explanation. We like questions to remain presentable (and even be improved) even after an answer has been accepted, to benefit other readers here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing several permutations of your code I think what you are trying to do needs to look a little something like this.

```
quickSort(arrayToSort, attributeToSortOn, left, right) {
    ...
}
...
function partition(arrayToSort, attributeToSortOn, left, right) {
    var pivot = student[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)][attributeToSortOn]
    ...
    while (arrayToSort[i][attributeToSortOn] < pivot) {
    ...
}
...
quickSort(studentsArray, 'studentNumber');
```

`quickSort` always needs the array to compare values at each position. You can't just pass `studentsArray.studentNumber` because the attribute to sort on is useless on it's own and the array has no knowledge of the types of object contained within it anyway.

Comment: Essentially that's what I ended up doing, I found this site and the code worked great: http://blog.bogojoker.com/2008/06/javascript-sort-an-array-of-objects/

thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a variable defined inside a function, in another function. Every function has its own scope, and in order to carry data between functions (inside the variables) you have to create a variable in the upper (global) scope. That means, you have to create the student and updatedStudentArray outside of the functions and use them without declaring in the functions (`sortStudentNumbers()` in this case)

```
var student;
var updatedStudentArray;

function swap(student, firstIndex, secondIndex){
    var temp = student[firstIndex];
    student[firstIndex] = student[secondIndex];
    student[secondIndex] = temp;
}

// ..................................
// ------ removed for clearity
// ..................................

function sortStudentNumbers() {    
    student = studentNumbersArray.name; // <-- THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING ERROR
    quickSort(student);
    updatedStudentArray = JSON.stringify(studentsArray);
    localStorage.setItem("students", updatedStudentArray); 
    location.reload();
}
```

These the mistakes I found. But still, when I execute this code I get a `studentsArray` is not defined error on the console. Where is your `studentsArray`? If you have it somewhere, then it should all work now.

EDIT:

After you created the second question, I had a quick chance to have a look at your modified code. Don't forget to update your question here.

*My Answer to your modified code:*
You have to set a "student" key in localStorage first, in order to use getItem() for it. You don't have anything in the localStorage, that is why your variable is not filled when you try to get the data from there. Thus, you are getting the error "`Cannot read property 'studentNumber' of null`".

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I actually made a mistake with the code that I copied onto this thread. I will try what you said when I have access to my laptop, and if it doesn't work then I will create a new thread with the proper code. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! May be you also upvote the answer, since it helped? :)

Comment: done! I still have some issues, so could you consider checking out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967481/is-it-possible-to-quicksort-objects-in-an-array-based-on-a-property-javascript

Comment: @name1234567, I updated my answer. Don't forget, the error you're getting is because of a non-filled variable. You cannot read a property of an undefined or null object.

Comment: thanks, but I do have a student key in my local storage (check out my updated code, I included my local storage). Also, no values are null (they either have a value or it is 0).
This is the built in sort function that works, if it helps:
`studentsArray.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.studentNumber) - parseFloat(b.studentNumber) } );`