# Is it possible to quicksort objects in an array based on a property? Javascript

Tags: javascript, quicksort

So I posted this question earlier but I copied the wrong code. This is the link incase you're interested: [Is it possible to quicksort objects based on their keys in an array, using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964962/is-it-possible-to-quicksort-objects-based-on-their-keys-in-an-array-javascript)

I have an array that has a bunch of objects in it. What I'm trying to do is reorder the array based on a specific property (that all of the objects possess).

So here is my code:

```
   studentsArray = [];
    studentsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));
    console.log(studentsArray);


        function swap(qStudent, firstIndex, secondIndex){
            var temp = qStudent[firstIndex];
            qStudent[firstIndex] = qStudent[secondIndex];
            qStudent[secondIndex] = temp;
        }

        function partition(qStudent, left, right) {

            var pivot   = qStudent[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
                i       = left,
                j       = right;


            while (i <= j) {

                while (qStudent[i] < pivot) {
                    i++;
                }

                while (qStudent[j] > pivot) {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j) {
                    swap(qStudent, i, j);
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            return i;
        }

        function quickSort(qStudent, left, right) {

            var index;

            if (qStudent.length > 1) {

                left = typeof left != "number" ? 0 : left;
                right = typeof right != "number" ? qStudent.length - 1 : right;

                index = partition(qStudent, left, right);
                if (left < index - 1) {
                    quickSort(qStudent, left, index - 1);
                }

                if (index < right) {
                    quickSort(qStudent, index, right);
                }

            }

            return qStudent;
        }





    console.log(studentsArray.studentNumber); // <-- THIS RETURNS undefined IN CONSOLE

    var students;
    var updatedStudentArray;
    var qStudent;

    function sortStudentNumbers() {        
        var qStudent = studentsArray.studentNumber;
        quickSort(qStudent);
        var updatedStudentArray = JSON.stringify(studentsArray);
        localStorage.setItem("students", updatedStudentArray); 
        location.reload();
    }
```

In my local storage, it looks like this:

```
Key: students
Value: [{"studentNumber":"123456","name":"Elisa Woman","presentNumber":0,"lateNumber":0,"absentNumber":0},{"studentNumber":"661211","name":"First Last","presentNumber":0,"lateNumber":0,"absentNumber":0},{"studentNumber":"941035","name":"Another Person","presentNumber":0,"lateNumber":0,"absentNumber":0}]
```

Whenever I try to quicksort studentArrays.studentNumber, Google Chrome (developer tools) gives me an error that says cannot read length of undefined.

When I use the built in sort function, it works perfectly, but unfortunately this is a school project so I have to break down the quick sort function. Is there anything wrong with my code? Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"So I posted this question earlier but I copied the wrong code."* That's what the "edit" link is for.

Comment: @AlanStallwood each student only has one input for the studentNumber so there isn't anything to sort there. What I'm trying to do is compare the studentNumber of ALL students in the array and sort them accordingly that way